# Dynamically project a Single County

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

Here is a simple yet inspiring topojson of a single state:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7061976

It is drawn by data from a json containing only that state as follows:

```
d3.json("va-counties.json", function(error, topo) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

What I want to do is dynamically project a county. Suppose there is a keyboard event or something that runs a function doing this: read into the parsed data, find the county id, and return a topojson feature of only that county. The difference between the above block and my case is that my json file would have all the counties in America, but I would only need 1 county at a time. Is there a way to achieve this in D3?

Just as a simple litmus test, for county id=1000, I tried:

```
  var current_county = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.counties).filter(function(d) { return d.id=1000;})),
      bounds = path.bounds(county);
```

Yet I kept getting persistent errors, no matter how much I toiled with it. Or it would stop throwing errors, but yet still not 'work'. Maybe `.filter()` is not the best tool for the job? What are other opinions?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first of all your `filter` syntax is wrong, I think you meant a comparison and not an assignment:

```
d.id === 1000
```

Second, `topojson.feature` returns GeoJSON which in an object and it's just not going to filter like that.  Your best bet is to filter it on the way in:

```
// filter the geometries of the topojson the structure you want
var geoCounty = topo.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d){
  return d.id === "51750";
});

// assign it back to the topojson object
topo.objects.counties.geometries = geoCounty;

// and off you go...
var county = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.counties),
    bounds = path.bounds(county);
```

Full running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.county {
  fill: #ccc;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 500,
    height = 300;

var projection = d3.geo.conicConformal()
    .parallels([38 + 02 / 60, 39 + 12 / 60])
    .rotate([78 + 30 / 60, 0])
    .scale(200000)
    .translate([0, 0]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/ce96ca06-e1ce-11e6-90ab-03e5986c4e20", function(error, topo) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var geoCounty = topo.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d){
    return d.id === "51750";
  });

  topo.objects.counties.geometries = geoCounty;

  var county = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.counties),
      bounds = path.bounds(county);

  projection
      .translate([width / 2 - (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2, height / 2 - (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2]);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(county)
      .attr("class", "county")
      .attr("d", path);

});

</script>
```

Comment: That makes so much sense now. Thank you for showing me the right convention. And you are right, I should have used a comparison `===`. I'm trying to test out your example, but I'm having issues with pointing the libraries. I keep getting "Error: Invalid or unexpected token." from the d3.projection.js file. I know D3.js is utf-8, is that one something different? What should I do??

Comment: @ArashHowaida, that error message should point you to a line of code.  When you inspect it does something look off?  Is the error really coming from `d3.projection.js` or your code?  It'll be next to impossible for me to debug that for you without reproducing it.

Comment: it says `d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js` line 1, not from the main html. Let me run some tests to see what encoding it is.

Comment: I am really baffled. Would your approach work if we omitted `d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js`? In favor of the standard projection way? I guess the angles would be different, but wouldn't be all that noticeable. I tried just changing the projection function, but it seems there were some other calls to the geo.projection script aside from the projection variable. Until I figure out what's wrong with my referencing of the library, we could use that as a solution.

Comment: @ArashHowaida, sure.  [Here is it](http://plnkr.co/edit/oWJMBdIMGBhyZFwOPj7X?p=preview) running with the standard `d3.geo.albersUsa`.

Comment: It works great! Thanks for the work-around. My last question is, why is it that when I change the json file it doesn't work? Dev tools didn't throw any errors, but nothing is projected. I'm just using the `us.json` here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json. You can try substituting to this json to see what I mean. Perhaps I need to change a few headers?

Comment: @ArashHowaida, it still works for me with that file.  I did notice, though, that the county ids in that file are **numeric** and **not strings** like in the previous file.  Here's the [county where I grew up](http://plnkr.co/edit/w3yeCT0VTlx0IlUHLZG6?p=preview).

Comment: Oh cool, good example. Unfortunately, even after removing the quotes, it doesn't work. I must have missed something obvious, I will get back to you when I figure it out. -- Edit, I figured it out. Turns out to be an issue of different id conventions.

Comment: We will soon have a world record for # of comments! Actually in all seriousness, I'm having trouble using this 'dynamically' as in the post title. I put the relevant parts of your code in a function, as I had this in mind for multiple calls (as in projecting different counties as per different events, but still 1 at a time.) Yet it seems the line: `topo.objects.counties.geometries = geoCounty;` or some other line is interfering with subsequent calls to the project function. I tried deleting that line, but it made everything really slow and changed the scale. Can  we make it more "dynamic"?

Comment: @ArashHowaida, my guess is that you have two problems.  First, is the `topo` object getting modified and then can't be used to filter subsequent counties.  You can [clone it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) to keep a working copy around.  Second, I'm not having any luck re-setting the projection's translation to use it over and over again.  I've found I have to recreate it on each "draw".  See updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/w3yeCT0VTlx0IlUHLZG6?p=preview), which draws random counties in Maryland.

Comment: Wow that's great, almost exactly what I was trying to do. Hopefully the computational efficiency isn't affected tooo much by 'drawing' each time. Either way, I can finish my project now, thanks for your continued support. I learned a lot from this.